# Intuitive effect size (and CI) for one-way comparison of group means?

Tags: confidence-interval, effect-size, intuition

I'm a big fan of common language effect sizes (e.g. McGraw and Wong's CL or Cohen's U3 - "what proportion of group 1 are higher than the average for group 2").  I've been scrabbling around trying to find something like that I could pull out of a *multiple group* comparison (as would be commonly analysed with one-way ANOVA).  But most of the literature seems to stop at two-group comparisons.

It occurred to me that a nice effect size would be either the CL or U3 of the highest mean compared with the lowest mean out of all of them.  Obviously, that is easy to compute.  But what I'm struggling with then is, is it possible to calculate a confidence interval on that?

At first glance it looks closely related to Hsu's MCB ("Multiple Comparisons to the Best"), except that that looks at unstandardised differences (and I'm looking for something standardised).  If there were an adaptation of Hsu's MCB to Cohen's d (instead of unstandardised diffs), that I guess would work for this, but I appreciate that is an added layer of complexity (needing to account for sampling of SD also), and I haven't been able to find anything that goes that far.

So:

1. Is there a way of calculating a confidence interval on the Cohen's d between the highest and lowest means in one-way ANOVA type setup?
2. Alternatively, is there a nice super-intuitive effect size (with CI) that I could use?

Comment: If you know which two groups you want to compare, does the question just reduce to how to find the confidence interval for Cohen's *d*, or for another effect size statistic for two groups ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico thanks for the comment!  I might be wrong, but I feel like that's not the case.  In much the same way that Hsu's MCB doesn't produce the same CIs as Dunnett's test -- even though both are comparing the same number of groups vs one group, the fact that the groups are chosen specifically to be the widest separated, I think has an impact?

Comment: @SalMangiafico Put it another way: if I had a million groups but all had the same population mean, I would expect the two groups with the furthest apart sample means to be much further apart than if I only had two groups, even though the population value for their mean diff is exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: That's a good point. ... One approach to get confidence intervals is to use bootstrapping.  ...  Here, I can imagine using a bootstrap approach including all sampled groups, and identifying the statistic of interest as the effect size statistic that would be the largest between any two groups.  I think that makes sense, and wouldn't be too difficult to implement with software.  I'd have to play with it to see how it shakes out practically.

Comment: @salmangiafico yes I think you might be right that bootstrapping would be the only way (with BCa as d is non pivotal)... It's a shame though as I was hoping to make a little tool to aid in teaching my students, and it would need to be quite light to run on the server. Wondering if I might have to give up and just use Cohen's f instead as that's somewhat intuitable I guess...